# in MySql Which is More faster and efficient, Manual Sequence or Auto Increment?

Tags: mysql, sequence, auto-increment

Which is More faster and efficient Manual Sequence or MySql Auto Increment? And which one we should use ? And which one is good for more efficient queries.

Comment: Why didn't you try and measure it yourself? ;) just sayin'

Comment: @JeffOrris Yes I've tried and checked but still have some doubt that is the reason I've asked this question.

Comment: You aren't serious with that, right? Have you read the MySQL docs?

Comment: @markus Yes I've read MySQL docs. And I got my answer we should use Auto increment feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create MySQL [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) column

```
CREATE TABLE xyz
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity By default. The starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.
>   for new rows

Comment: My question is which one is more faster ? auto - increment or sequence ?

Comment: auto - increment  is faster